# Name already used in existing object PL/SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a procedure but its saying the name already exist and im a little confused because I havent created it for my procedure. I want it to display the information from the rows.I am not sure its because of the Cursor or from the Trips_ID.  I am fairly new to sql so I am not sure if my explanation of is good.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRIPS(Trip_ID in NUMBER) IS
          CURSOR Trips_CURSOR IS SELECT * FROM TRIPS
where TRIPS_ID = T_INFO;
T_ROW Trips_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The ID of this trip is ' || T_INFO);
 FOR T_ROW IN Trips_CURSOR LOOP    
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Date of the trip is ' || T_ROW.DATE_OF_TRIP);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Destination town of the Trip ' || T_ROW.Destination_Town);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Source town is  ' || T_ROW.Source_Town);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't consider an object type as part of a namespace, so it doesn't allow to create objects with the same name, but of different types. Your procedure has the same name as  the table (`TRIPS`).

You may check names already in use by `select * from user_objects`.

> ```
> create table t(id int)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create function t return number is
> begin
>   return null;
> end;
> /
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=42670750ce3b0467dbc4dcd7d4417814)*

And a side note of the same type: variables in PL/SQL should have different name compared to table's columns, because Oracle cannot know if it is a variable or a table column when used in `select/where`.